# Processbar Loop With Stop At Hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-animations

I want to create a processbar that perform a function `foo()` when it grows to 100% width.

HTML:

```
<div></div>
```

CSS:

```
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
height: 2px;
width: 0px;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
```

So I tried it to do this with a CSS animation.

JS:

```
var duration = parseInt("15");
var bar = $("[...] div");
doSomething = (function () {
    bar.css({
        "animation-duration" : duration+"s",
        "animation-name" : "expand",
        "animation-timing-function" : "linear"
    });
    bar.on("animationend oAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd webkitAnimationEnd", function(e) {
        bar.css("animation-name", "none");
        foo();
        $(this).off(e);
    });
    doSomething();
});
```

This works perfectly in the first run, but it doesn't loop.

But with this solution I can add a stop at `hover` easily with:

CSS:

```
 animation-play-state: paused;
```

I tried a solution with jQuery `animate()`, the loop works but I don't know how to add a stop at hover and pause the animation, because there are no option in jQuery to do something like this. Sure I can stop the animation, but when I run it again, it plays the rest of the width with the same duration.

JS:

```
doSomething = (function () {
    /* First try
    interval = setInterval(function(){
        bar.animate({
            width: "100%",
        }, duration, "linear", function() {
            bar.css("width", "0px");
            foo();
        });
    }, 0);*/
    bar.animate({
        width: "100%",
    }, duration, "linear", function() {
        bar.css("width", "0px");
        foo();
    });
});
$("[parent of bar]")
    .mouseenter(function() {
        bar.stop();
    })
    .mouseleave(function() {
        bar.finish(); /* Animate: 100% - currentWidth in duration */
    });
```

So any other ideas?

Comment: Maybe a demo would help but with the CSS solution you'd have to re-attach the animation after a specific period of time (say time out or delay) or after execution of `foo()` is completed for it to restart. Otherwise there is no animation to be executed due to `animation-name: none` setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you are nullifying or removing the animation when the `animationend` event is fired. Due to this, the loop won't work. If you want to support looping then you could either recall `doSomething` at the end of processing of the `foo()` function to re-attach the animation and the event handler.

In the below snippet, the `foo()` function will display "Animation Completed.." text after the animation is completed and then after a 2s delay restart the animation.

```js
var duration = parseInt("15");
var bar = $("div.animated-element");
doSomething = (function() {
  bar.css({
    "animation-duration": duration + "s",
    "animation-name": "expand",
    "animation-timing-function": "linear"
  });
  bar.on("animationend oAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd webkitAnimationEnd", function(e) {
    bar.css("animation-name", "none");
    foo();
    $(this).off(e);
  });
});
doSomething();

function foo() {
  var op = $('div.output');
  op.html("Animation Completed....");
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    doSomething();
    op.html("");
  }, 2000);
}
```

```css
div.animated-element {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 0px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
@keyframes expand {
  from {
    width: 0px;
  }
  to {
    width: 200px;
  }
}
div.animated-element:hover {
  animation-play-state: paused !important; /* important is needed because of inline animation styles or you can set this also inline using jQuery*/
}

div.output{
  margin-top: 50px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<div class='animated-element'></div>
<div class='output'></div>
```

---

Or, you can also the `animationiteration` event to fire the `foo()` function at the end of each iteration of an animation and use `animationend` to fire `foo()` when animation is completed once and for all.

In the below snippet, the `foo()` function will display "Animation Completed.." (misleading text but you get the point) text after each iteration of the animation, after a 2s delay the text would go away but the animation would continue to run until its 5 iterations are completed. Finally after 5 iterations, animation would be stopped.

```js
var duration = parseInt("15");
var bar = $("div.animated-element");
doSomething = (function() {
  bar.css({
    "animation-duration": duration + "s",
    "animation-name": "expand",
    "animation-timing-function": "linear",
    "animation-iteration-count" : "5"
  });
  bar.on("animationend oAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd webkitAnimationEnd", function(e) {
    bar.css("animation-name", "none");
    foo();
    $(this).off(e);
  });
  bar.on("animationiteration oAnimationIteration MSAnimationIteration mozAnimationIteration webkitAnimationIteration", function(e) {
    foo();
  });  
});
doSomething();

function foo() {
  var op = $('div.output');
  op.html("Animation Completed....");
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    op.html("");
  }, 2000);
}
```

```css
div.animated-element {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 0px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
@keyframes expand {
  from {
    width: 0px;
  }
  to {
    width: 200px;
  }
}
div.animated-element:hover {
  animation-play-state: paused !important; /* important is needed because of inline animation styles or you can set this also inline using jQuery*/
}

div.output{
  margin-top: 50px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<div class='animated-element'></div>
<div class='output'></div>
```

You can read more about the various **animation related events** in the [**spec here**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-animations/#AnimationEvent-types).

Comment: Thank you dude, the timeout was the missing thing! I dont know why javascript doesn't loop without the timeout, but hey it works :)

Comment: @Coli: Happy to know that it helped :) When you don't use timeout, the properties are removed (via `animation-name: none`) and added (via `foo()`) immediately and so its possible that the UA sees no change. Since it sees no change, it would assume that one iteration of the animation was already completed and does nothing. When we add a timeout, there is a time lapse between the removal of the animation and its re-addition which makes the browser forget the old state.

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('.childSpan').addClass('progress');
            $('.childSpan').on('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function() {
                console.log('100%');//call the foo() function here
                $('.childSpan').removeClass('progress');
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $('.childSpan').addClass('progress');
                }, 1);
            });
        });
```

```css
@-webkit-keyframes progress {
    0%{width:0%;}
    50%{width:50%;}
    100%{width:100%;} 
}

@-moz-keyframes progress {
    0%{width:0%;}
    50%{width:50%;}
    100%{width:100%;} 
}

@-o-keyframes progress {
    0%{width:0%;}
    50%{width:50%;}
    100%{width:100%;} 

}

@keyframes progress {
    0%{width:0%;}
    50%{width:50%;}
    100%{width:100%;} 

} 
.progress {
    -webkit-animation-name: progress;
    -moz-animation-name: progress;
    -o-animation-name: progress;
    animation-name: progress;
    -webkit-animation: progress 2s  linear;
    -moz-animation: progress 2s  linear;
    -o-animation: progress 2s  linear;
    -ms-animation: progress 2s  linear;

}

.parentDiv:hover > .childSpan {
    -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
    animation-play-state: paused;
}
.parentDiv{width:300px;background:black;height:50px;}
.childSpan{background: red none repeat scroll 0 0;display: block;height: 50px;width:0%;}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<div id="processDiv" class="parentDiv">
 <span id="process" class="childSpan">
 
 </span>
</div>
```

Just Try this out,only need to add and remove the class after animation end.

In case you don't need the event after completion then the rest can be done through css only need to change the animation type to

```
-webkit-animation: shake 2s infinite linear;
-moz-animation: shake 2s infinite linear;
-o-animation: shake 2s infinite linear;
-ms-animation: shake 2s infinite linear;
```

and by default add the progress class on the span, no need of any jquery code for this case.

Comment: Essentially the same. The only difference is that you are adding/removing class whereas my answer is adding/removing properties. I am just wondering if OP is trying to set different `animation-duration` in their actual code (based on how they are using a variable and `parseInt`). If that is the case then adding/removing class would be very tough as you'd have to edit CSS rules.

Comment: To make the duration dynamic we need to add the css (related to the animation) through jquery with variable duration of animation as done in the original code for bar elemnt.

Comment: That's exactly what I was saying (and used in my answer). I am not putting down your answer in anyway, just saying that add/remove class may or may not be the easiest approach depending on what OP wants.